# How do I create an array of each line in a text file?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, variables, readfile

I am new to C#!
Whenever I wanted to parse info from a .txt file in other programs, I would create a loop that reads the entire file and saves each line as an array named after the file. I don't know how to do that in C# and looking for help, here is an example of my process:

```
//This is not a programming language, just my thought process on how it works;

loop
{
    ReadFile "File1.txt", Line i, save as vTempLine
    if (vTempLine != null)
    {
        vCount = i
        vFile1Array[i] = vTempLine
    }
    else
    {
        vCountLoop1 = vCount
        vTempLine = ""
        vCount = ""
        Break
    }
}
```

I come from `AutoHotkey`, and this is a minor example. Basically:

1. The Loop repeats until break
2. First command reads a `.txt` file one line at a time, told to read line `i`, which is the current loop's line. Saves this line as a variable string `vTempLine`.
3. Checks to make sure the line exists, then saves the current line count as `vCount` and the current line as `vFile1Array`, where the current array count is equal to the loop. This way each array number is equal to the line it was formed from (skipping the starting array variable 0).
4. If the line in the file read doesn't exist, it assumes end of file and saves the temporary variables into long term variables, then closes those temporary variables and breaks the loop.
5. The ending result will have two variables, one named `vCountLoop1`, which has the number of lines in the file.
6. and the second variable is an array, with each array variable stored as a line from the text file (skipping the storage of array 0).

Comment: Google `StreamReader` `List<string>`, `List.Add` and `List.ToArray()`

Comment: You should explain what is going wrong; you're just saying what you're trying to do at the moment.

Comment: `var myArray = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt")`. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Benjamin W. - nothing is going wrong, im just new to C# and trying to grasp how to save an array from a text file.

Comment: Just saying that the question is not super clear at the moment: you say "How can I do X?", then you post code and describe what the code does. Or is it what the code should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not very fine but are you thinking about something like that?

```
string vTempLine;    // Not needed to be declared outside the loop
int i = 0;
int vCountLoop1 = 0; // Not needed: Might be the same as i
Dictionary<int, string> vFile1Array = new Dictionary<int, string>(); // Or use a List<string>

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("File1.txt")) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        // if statement is not needed here
        i++;
        vTempLine = sr.ReadLine();
        vCountLoop1 = i;
        vFile1Array[i] = vTempLine; 
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "not needed to be declared outside the loop", will the variable be removed from memory when the loop ends if it is only declared inside a loop?

Comment: I think File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt") as suggested in the comments is a better solution. If you were to do this yourself, I would use a `List<string>` and convert it to an array (`.ToArray()`) at the end if needed, rather than a dictionary.

Comment: @EricJ. Would this work with just the 1 line of code?

Comment: Yes. `string[] vFile1Array = File.ReadAllLines("File1.txt");`

Comment: @EricJ. Okay, thank you. Do you know how i can recall the number of variables saved in the array? Because I would also need to get the number of lines in the file as well

Comment: `int numberOfVariables = vFile1Array.Length`

Comment: Yes the inside variable will be removed when the loop ends.